# Magento 2 Bug | Customer Places Order in Cart, then out of stock when checking out

Tags: magento2, checkout, out-of-stock

On our Magento 2 page we have a bit of customers placing an item in cart (in stock) but when checking out after placing order, it gives an error saying the item is out of stock... but it places the order. No order confirmation success page provided.

Any clue on what this means and how to fix it? It has been a huge issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution? please share it.

Comment: I had the same problem. The reason was that I had faulty code in my order confirmation-mail in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that backorder is enabled? You can check here:

> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory